# Overriding a parent's classmethod with an instance method

Tags: python, inheritance

I may not be thinking about this in a Pythonic way.
I have a class, SqlDB, which uses fetchall to get all of the rows from a cursor:

```
class SqlDB(object):

    @classmethod
    def executeQuery(cls, cursor, query, params):
        # code to set up and execute query here
        rows = cls.fetchRows(cursor)
        # other code here

    @classmethod
    def fetchRows(cls, cursor):
        print "in class SqlDB"
        return cursor.fetchall()
```

So I want to add a subclass that uses fetchmany, and gets initialized with a batch size:

```
class SqlDBBatch(SqlDB):

    def __init__(self, batchsize=1000):
        self.batchsize = batchsize

    def fetchRows(self, cursor):
        print "in SqlDBBatch"
        while True:
            results = cursor.fetchmany(self.batchsize)
        # more code
```

Of course, since the original executeQuery function is calling fetchRows on the class passed into it, I'm getting `TypeError: unbound method fetchRows() must be called with SqlDBBatch instance as first argument (got CursorDebugWrapper instance instead)` when I try to call executeQuery on an instance of SqlDBBatch.  Is there any way to achieve what I'm going for, where I can override a parent's classmethod with an instance method, and have the parent class able to call the subclass implementation?

Comment: Instance methods make sense only in the context of an instance. In class methods you don't have an instance to call instance methods on. This doesn't make sense really. Why `executeQuery` and `fetchRows` have to be class methods? They seem to make perfect sense as instance methods...

Comment: The `SqlDB` parent class doesn't have any state attached to it, since it's doing a `fetchall()` every time with no parameters, so it seems like it would make sense as a class method.  For `SqlDBBatch`, it's initializing with a batch size so it could use it with its `fetchmany()` call, so the value in the instance would affect how many rows to fetch at once.

Comment: 1) Seems odd that a DB class has no state - usually it's a DB connection. 2) Lack of state isn't enough to decide on using a class method. And problems in your design are a great example of this.

Comment: I'm aware the design is at least somewhat flawed, as that's the main point of the question.  So would you recommend making `executeQuery` an instance method in this case? It just seems like every instance of the class SqlDB would be exactly the same, so it would seem to follow that `executeQuery` would make sense as a `@classmethod`.

Comment: "every instance of the class SqlDB would be exactly the same" all instances of any class are always exactly the same in terms of methods they have. Again, this is not a reason to make something a `classmethod`. However, *references* to `SqlDB` can point to either `SqlDB` or `SqlDBBatch` which will make the behaviour different, depending on a concrete instance you don't need/want to know about. And that's the whole point of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is with parents or inheritance, but simply with calling an instance method from a class method.

```
class Bar(object):
    def caller(self,x='cx'):
        print('bar caller',self)
        self.myfn(x)
    @classmethod
    def classcaller(cls,x='ccx'):
        print('bar class caller',cls)
        cls.myfn(x)
    def myfn(self,x=None):
        print('in bar instance',self,x)
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'BarInstance'

Bar().myfn()
# ('in bar instance', BarInstance, None)
Bar.myfn(Bar())
# ('in bar instance', BarInstance, None)
Bar().caller()
# ('bar caller', BarInstance)
# ('in bar instance', BarInstance, 'cx')
Bar.classcaller(Bar())
# ('bar class caller', <class '__main__.Bar'>)
# ('in bar instance', BarInstance, None)
Bar().classcaller(Bar())
# same

# the following produce:
#     TypeError: unbound method myfn() must be called with Bar instance ...
# Bar.myfn()
# Bar.caller()
# Bar.classcaller()
# Bar().classcaller()
```

With this single class, I can readily call `myfn` from the instance `caller` method, but have pass a separate `Bar()` instance if using `classcaller`.  Calling the classmethod with `Bar()` is no different from calling it with `Bar`.

Even if a classmethod is called with an instance, it's the `klass` that is passed through, not the `obj`. http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods

```
class ClassMethod(object):
     "Emulate PyClassMethod_Type() in Objects/funcobject.c"
     ...
     def __get__(self, obj, klass=None):
          if klass is None:
               klass = type(obj)
          def newfunc(*args):
               return self.f(klass, *args)
          return newfunc
```

Why are you using `@classmethod`?  Do you call them with just class name, or with instances?  Even if the parent class versions don't use instance attributes, it might simpler to use instance methods at all levels. Python got along for many years without this decorator (added in 2.4).

Comment: The error is saying that it's getting a cursor as the first argument rather than `self`, since I'm calling it on the class from the parent class.  I'm trying to effectively call `SqlDBBatch(batchsize=1000).executeQuery("queryhere")`, and have the child `fetchRows(cursor)` used instead of the parent.

Comment: Experimenting more, I've concluded that the problem is with using a `classmethod` to call an instance method.  It isn't about parent classes.  `executeQuery` gets the `SqlDBBatch` class, but not the `SqlDBBatch()` instance.